# ADF af:inputText constantly getting focus after validation

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

After doing a programatic validation on a row in a table, the field that has the validation error keeps taking focus

`FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            input.setValid(false);
            context.validationFailed();
            context.addMessage(input.getClientId(context),
            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Message", null));`

[image]

I have immediate set to true, but that doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont understand... field still has focus even after you have change the  input to the right value?

Answer (score 0):

Try to drag and drop the table again or check if autosubmit=true

Comment: I do have autosubmit=true.  If i don't then my valueChangeListener won't fire.  I'm guessing that's what causing the re-submits tho.  Any ideas?